# Unrequested Socket.IO Connection

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, socket.io

When I navigate to a sub page of my site, my socket.io server is running the connection module for the index page.

Here is the complete console log upon navigation to www.example.com/query

```
authenticated updated ==> { GbLZ5jxHz0S5uyNNAAAA: { user: 'yrn1jro2fw1nk4dyy4', group: 'uehw1o2grq1oy11y9xrgyw' } }
client connected to INDEX with id GbLZ5jxHz0S5uyNNAAAA
preloading index
client connected to QUERY with id GbLZ5jxHz0S5uyNNAAAA
preloading query
```

My main question deals with I am getting the second and third lines. I expect to connect to "QUERY" but not to "INDEX".

When I navigate to www.example.com the console prints as expected with a single connection.

Here is my entire server.js file that I just simplified and ran to generate the simplified console log above. You can ignore the authentication stuff, I mostly included that for people that might find it useful.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var util = require("./js/util.js");

var authenticated = {}; // [socket_id:{user:000,group:000},socket_id:{user:000,group:000}] // stores currently authenticated sockets

server.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/query', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/query.html');
});

 app.get('/favicon.ico', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/favicon.ico');
 });

app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use("/images", express.static(__dirname + '/images'));

var mysql = require('mysql');
var db = mysql.createConnection({host:'localhost',user:'root',password:'fakepw',database:'baseofdata'});
db.connect();

var index = io.of('/').on('connection', function (socket) {
    // console.log(socket);
    console.log("client connected to INDEX with id",socket.id);
    socket.on("authenticate",function(data){
        console.log("authenticate data ==> ",data);
        db.query("SELECT user,usergroup FROM group_users INNER JOIN users ON group_users.user = users.id WHERE username = ? AND password = ?",[data.user,data.pass],function(err, rows) {
            console.log("auth returned ==> ",rows,err);
            if (err === null && rows.length > 0)
            {
                authenticated[socket.id] = {user:rows[0].user,group:rows[0].usergroup};
                encoded = {};
                encoded.user = util.encode(rows[0].user);
                encoded.usergroup = util.encode(rows[0].usergroup);
                socket.emit("authenticated",encoded);
                preload();
            }
            else socket.emit("unauthorized");
        });
    });

    if (typeof authenticated[socket.id] !== 'object')
    {
        console.log(socket.id,"does not exist -- sending unauthorized");
        socket.emit("unauthorized");
    }
    else preload();

    // OTHER INDEX LISTENERS HERE

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        delete authenticated[socket.id];
        console.log(socket.id,"deleted");
    });

    function preload()
    {
        console.log("preloading index");
        // PRELOAD INDEX
    }
});

var query = io.of('/query').on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("client connected to QUERY with id",socket.id);

    if (typeof authenticated[socket.id] !== 'object') 
    {
        console.log(socket.id,"does not exist -- sending unauthorized");
        socket.emit("unauthorized");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("preloading query"); 
        // PRELOAD QUERY
    }

    // OTHER QUERY LISTENERS HERE

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        delete authenticated[socket.id];
        console.log(socket.id,"deleted");
    });
});

io.use(function(socket, next){
    if (socket.handshake.query.u !== 'null' && socket.handshake.query.u !== undefined)
    {
        authenticated[socket.id] = {};
        authenticated[socket.id].user = socket.handshake.query.u;
        authenticated[socket.id].group = socket.handshake.query.g;
        console.log("authenticated updated ==>",authenticated);
    }
    if (socket.request.headers.cookie) return next();
    next(new Error('Authentication error'));
});
```

Here is my applicable client code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Query Page</title>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" sizes="32x32" type="image/ico">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect("127.0.0.1/query",{query:"u=" + readCookie("u") + "&g=" + readCookie("g")});
```

I am clearly missing something. Also, I am new to node and socket.io and would appreciate any guidance.

EDIT: 
Changed edits to an answer.

Also changed the client connection from "example.com" to the server's IP address. Though, I doubt it mattered but I wondered if the issue was related to my DNS redirecting URLs.

Comment: Do you realize that in a socket.io connection, you connect to a server, not to a particular path on that server?

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah, I am using namespaces. Again, I am new and maybe my whole approach is flawed. I should add that the site functions well, there is one issue when a second user connects but I figured it was related to this issue so I hope this solves it.

Comment: @jfriend00 I just had to change "var index = io.of('/').on.." ==> to ==> "var index = io.of('/index').on.." Thank you for your comment, it got me thinking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root "namespace" does not act as I though it would.

Change

```
var index = io.of('/').on('connection', function (socket) {
```

to

```
var index = io.of('/index').on('connection', function (socket) {
```

So the actual index page will not rely on the default namespace but instead have it's own module.